# inherited class and properties not included in JSON result from ASP.NET Core API

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, asp.net-apicontroller

I have a simple model that I try to serialize to JSON, but some properties don't get included in the result. When my object inherits from a base class, the properties of the base class doesn't appear in the json.

In the JSON string "searchModel" is {}

**SearchModelBase.cs**:

```
public interface ISearchModelBase
{
    SearchTypes Type { get; set; }
    string SearchString { get; set; }
}

public abstract class SearchModelBase : ISearchModelBase
{
    public SearchModelBase(SearchTypes type, string searchString)
    {
        this.Type = type;
        this.SearchString = searchString;
    }

    public SearchTypes Type { get; set; }

    public string SearchString { get; set; }
}

public enum SearchTypes
{
    User,
    Site
}
```

**AssetsDefaultSearchModel.cs**:

```
public interface IAssetsDefaultSearchModel : ISearchModelBase
{

}

public class AssetsDefaultSearchModel : SearchModelBase, IAssetsDefaultSearchModel
{
    public AssetsDefaultSearchModel(SearchTypes type, string searchString) : base(type, searchString) 
    {

    }
}
```

**JSON**:

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "displayName": "FFU Samarin",
            "data": {
                "appId": 3,
                "displayName": "FFU Samarin",

                ..........
```

In Visual Studio each item in the collection contains AssetsDefaultSearchModel with values in both properties:
[image]

Comment: Is this .net-core-3?  Which serialization library are you using?

Answer (score 2):

add below code to your Startup.cs

```
services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson();
```

you can use the [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson) NuGet package

Answer (score 1):

In the interface derived from ISearchResultBase I had to define a new property with the new keyword. I then return an object derived from IAssetsDefaultSearchResult (without replicating the property in the class) and it worked as expected.

```
public interface IAssetsDefaultSearchResult : ISearchResultBase
{
    new ISearchModelBase SearchModel { get; }

    string DisplayName { get; }

    object Data { get; }

    TagBuilder HtmlTag { get; }
}
```